# Scala named argument: recursive call

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, named-parameters

Very strange situation.

I have the following code snippet:

```
case class SomeResponse(
    ok: Boolean,
    result: Seq[Data]
)

class TestContainer {

    def testMethod() = {

        val response = SomeResponse(
                  // vvv - issue is here
          ok = true, Seq(getStubData)
                  // ^^^
        )

        val result = Json.toJson(response)
    }

    def getStubData = Data(10, "James")
}
```

When I am not specifying parameter name, everything compiles and works as expected.

But when I explicitly set parameter name

```
val response = SomeResponse(
           // vvv - issue is here
ok = true, result = Seq(getStubData)
           // ^^^
```

compiler complies with the following message:

```
Error:(63, 30) recursive value response needs type
    val result = Json.toJson(response)
```

Is there any specific compiler behavior for named arguments?

Comment: What is `Data`? and which Json library are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, as you can see, `Data` is a simple case class. I am using `play.api.libs.json.Json` shipped with PlayFramework 2.6.3

Comment: Are you sure your definition of `SomeResponse` is correct?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you right. There should be `Seq[Data]`

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of the interaction between a semi-solved issue in scala and another one in sbt:

- [scala/bug#5091](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5091)
- [sbt/sbt#1928](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1928)

Judging by the comments there and in linked issues, during type inference the compiler treats all `x = y` statements in the same way, leading to a cycle when trying to infer `result` above.

Workarounds:

- provide the explicit type of `result` or even `response` above; anything that will break the type inference cycle will do
- rename `val result`